# Gson exception while parsing date is caused by system language or Android version?

Tags: java, android, parsing, datetime, gson

I have an application server running on Amazon, which is set to `en_US` language. I am developing an Android app and running it in two devices, one with *Android 4.4* set to en_US and another one with *Android 6.0* set to `pt_BR`.

The app is running normally on the first device, but in the second I got the following error:

```
JsonSyntaxException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "May 17, 2016"
```

I have and object (Request) where one of the fields is an java.sql.Date. The method is (line 6 throws the exception):

```
1    public List<Request> getRequestList(String jsonString) {
2        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonString);
3        JsonElement jsonElement = jsonObject.get("requestList");
4        Type requestListType = new TypeToken<List<Request>>() {
5        }.getType();
6        List<Request> requestList = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, requestListType);
7        return requestList;
8    }
```

I would like to know if anyone had the same problem and how to solve it, if the problem is caused by the Android versions or the system languages on the devices. Thank you fellas!

Comment: How do you parse the dates? 
Provide some code, please!

Comment: did you try to set the date format of gson already? Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").create();

Comment: Thanks avjr.  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").create() solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

you may format the gson date with

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").create()
```